# Add message if contents of list item equal zero

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add the message "Product is out of stock" to a product layout with jQuery that appears if the stock of a product is equal to zero. The code I have right now will show the message I want if I use a double equal `==` comparison, but not if I use an exact equal comparison `===`. What am I doing incorrectly in my code to cause this occurrence? With with the `==` comparison, my code will also add the message to any product with `"N/A"` in `<li id="stock"></li>` item as well, which is not intended.

html:

```
<ul class="nobullet" id="product-info">
    <li id="stock" style="display:none;">0</li>
    <li id="stockMessage"></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
var stockAmount = $("#stock").text();

if (stockAmount == 0){
    $("#stockMessage").html("<span style='color:red;'>Product is out of stock.</span>");
}
```

live page: http://www.redlakewalleye.com/main-menu/walleye-1/walleye-cheeks-fresh-frozen

Comment: **You commented the `#stock` element**, how you expect jQuery to get that element and it's text?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I updated to be display: none; instead. Thanks.

Comment: Well, that makes now a big difference. You should notify that important change in your Question.

Comment: @Phorden In that case, please update your question to reflect the correct code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery function `.text()` returns a string. You are comparing a string with a number with this code:

```
stockAmount == 0
```

So type conversion will need to be done.  The `==` operator does that automatically, but the `===` operator will fail as it does not do type conversion.

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) regarding `==`:

> The equality operator converts the operands if they are not of the same type, then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a number or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if possible; else if either operand is a string, the string operand is converted to a number if possible. If both operands are objects, then JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in memory.

And `===`:

> The identity operator returns true if the operands are strictly equal (see above) with no type conversion.

If you wanted to use the `===` operator, you could first parse the element text to an integer using code similar to the following:

```
var stockAmount = parseInt($("#stock").text(), 10);

if (stockAmount === 0){
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. I understand my coding issue much better now.

Comment: @Phorden Glad I could help. If this answers your question you should mark it as accepted (click the check mark under the voting arrows).

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't comment out `<!-- -->` an element whose text should be retrieved by JS (jQuery) Hide it using any other approach.

```
var stockAmount = +$("#stock").text(); // "0" // Yey it works now!!
               // ^---- unary + to convert to Number

if (!stockAmount){ // or use: stockAmount === 0 
    $("#stockMessage").html("<span style='color:red;'>Product is out of stock.</span>");
}
```

I won't cover the topic about *`What's the difference between == and ===`* cause it's already answered both on Goog ans SO.